# Flutter Camera - Choose lens?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Is there a way in Flutter to choose the specific camera lens on Android? Many modern smartphones have a multi camera setup, such as a telephoto and macro lens, what is the method to see what is available and switch to a specific lens?

Comment: Did you try calling `availableCameras()` which should return all available cameras as an array?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I only get two cameras, back and front. My phone has 4 front cameras.

Comment: Have you attempted to utilize the native API to access the available cameras? If your particular cameras cannot be accessed through the native API, the Flutter API will be unable to assist you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling `availableCameras()`, you only get front and back cameras. However, if you use the same parameters as the other Descriptions, and increment the `name` String, you can access the other cameras.

Example: My telephoto lens has the name string `'2'`.

> NOTE: Sensors such as 50MP lens may not be available as the manufacturer has locked them down, disallowing them for third party applications.